# Error While creating Custom Framework and xcframework

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, xcframework

I am creating a Framework where i am adding multiple Third Party Libraries manually. and creating a Fat framework `SomeFrameworkName.framework` using the script below

```
#!/bin/sh

UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

# make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build

# Step 2. Copy the framework structure (from iphoneos build) to the universal folder
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"

# Step 3. Copy Swift modules from iphonesimulator build (if it exists) to the copied framework directory
SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule/."
if [ -d "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" ]; then
cp -R "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule"
fi

# Step 4. Create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the copied framework directory
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"

# Step 5. Convenience step to copy the framework to the project's directory
cp -R "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${PROJECT_DIR}"

# Step 6. Convenience step to open the project's directory in Finder
open "${PROJECT_DIR}"
```

After Archiving i am able to get the framework file but when i try to add that framework into the demo project it gives me multiple errors as follows:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/TestIOS.framework/TestIOS
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E76B5EA8-2E7C-44A4-BDCC-A8AB0B37E500/TestAshishDemo.app/TestDemo
  Reason: image not found
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
```

or else any library names comes in the picture.

and whenever i try to create the xcframework file i get the following error

```
Failed to build module from its module interface; it may have been damaged or it may have triggered a bug in the Swift compiler when it was produced
```

i am on a crucial stage to solve this error. Anyone if facing the same issue or faced the same along the way they created framework Please Help me out

- XCode Version - 12.5.1

Comment: Do the included frameworks have “build library for distribution” set? If you’re using CocoaPods you can do this in a post install step.

Comment: @Yonat I have set "Build Library for Distribution" to "YES" for all the methods like from carthage , Pods , manually adding to Framework

Answer (score 0):

In your target project, did you try to embed the Framework ?

(Old XCode screenshot of mine here)

[image]

Comment: Yes i Did Add All the required framework inside ```General -> Framework and Libraries``` For every Process which i have followed like adding libraries through pods, Carthage as well as manually

Comment: Just in case, check the embed status of the added framework. Hopefully the dynamic linker shouldn't complain anymore.

Comment: I have added all the framework in ```Embed & Sign``` If this is what you are suggesting ?? or else i did not understand the possibility you are saying

Comment: I am sure it is somehow related to the Architecture ```arm64``` and ```Apple silicon M1``` But somehow i am not sure if anyone can shed some lights on the same or direct me what to do ?? or should i try using any other Xcode version ??